# What will be the maximum data/URL can be stored per key in cache storage?

Tags: caching, browser-cache, service-worker

What will be the maximum data/URL(keys) can be stored per key in cache storage? By default chrome only show upto 49 URLs. Is 49 is maximum?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a hard maximum that I'm aware of. There are [overall limits](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/) on the amount of storage space that a single origin has access to, and those limits apply to all forms of storage (Cache Storage API, IndexedDB, local storage, etc.), rather than applying to the number of keys in a single `Cache` instance.

Chrome's Cache Storage viewer in the Applications panel does show only 50 entries per page, but you can navigate forward and backwards to see additional entries beyond the first 50.

Comment: Ya.Got the answer before itself.Thanks for replying.   See Comments in below link :- https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/